# Table in Jasper iReport Designer

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a table in Jasper iReport Designer. When the report is executed,it shows the same table multiple times.
Although only single dataset & table is used.Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent repetition of data display in report?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504817/how-to-prevent-repetition-of-data-display-in-report)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your table component into the SUMMARY band because detail band repeats the record for every row in dataset.

If you really need to put it in the detail band, you can try set the 
  table property "printWhenExpression"  to $V{REPORT_COUNT} == 1