# bar chart in jasper idesigner printing twice in preview?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have configured bar chart in idesigner but when I clcik the preview it is showing twice. Any idea why could this happen.

Thanks.

Comment: What report band have you placed your chart in?

Comment: It is showing 10 charts in total and 2 graphs per each page. I think something I have given in the chart data might be wrong. I have given series expression as $F{Name} & Category Expression as $F{Name} and value expression is $F{NoOfMailSent}.

Comment: All the 10 reports are same. I guess this is something to do with reset type and increment type property because when I change them I see there are some changes happening but still there are 10 charts instead of one.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Table in Jasper iReport Designer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15608309/876298)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put your graph component into the SUMMARY band because detail band is repeat the records for every row in dataset.

I think you have put the graph in detail band so ,If you really need to put it in the detail band, you can try set the table property "printWhenExpression" to $V{REPORT_COUNT} == 1

To set the property to make chart in Summary or in detail band, you can edit in XML code or through designer you can add bands and move charts.

Comment: Hi Sharad, Thanks for the reply. That worked absolutely fine. But I don't know why there are total 3 pages coming up with last 2 pages blank. How to avoid these blank pages? Can you suggest some good resources to learn the effective ways of Jasper Reports using iReportDesigner

Comment: One more question is which property need to set to make the chart as Summary band or detail band?

Comment: I have query for 10 bars but it is showing only 9. I changed the query to take 5 but still it is showing 4. Any reason why this could happen?

Comment: Any idea? I still didn't get all the data from the query which means last Bar is missing. And also I got the extra pages with no graphs but heading.

Comment: To set the property to make chart in Summary or in detail band, you can edit in XML code or through designer you can add bands and move charts.

Comment: Check the query, this must be showing 10 records but the column which you are referring for bars will have 9 records or may be including some null values.

Comment: to remove blank pages reduce the band height of the band where you have put the graph.