# Create multiple tables from single query in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have to create a report where main thing is a list of items. On the first page there is also supposed to be a bunch of tables that show figures counted from the list (things like amounts of different types of items etc).

Here is an example to demonstrate the idea. List of the items is actually quite long and goes for multiple pages. Other statistics will be listed only on the front page.

(..edit: seems I can't post images yet..)

I have a database query that retrieves the data for the item list. The question is: **Is there a way to use this single query to form all the needed statistics?**

All the statistics are such that they can be formed with for example using jaspers groups and variables. I also know how to achieve the desired result by using a subreport for each table (and then I'd even be able tailor the query for each table to directly result the wanted values) but I would like to avoid running the same (or almost same) query for multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your table component into the SUMMARY band because detail band repeats the record for every row in dataset.

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608309/table-in-jasper-ireport-designer/15608379#15608379)

Comment: Can I somehow avoid performing a distinct database query for each table? And if so, is it possible to group the results based on different fields in the different tables?

Comment: You do not have to create different database for each table , you can use the same database for all the tables and It is not possible to group the results based on different fields.

Comment: As I'll have to group the different tables based on different fields (in one table the count of different types and in another one the count of different destinations etc.) it seems that I can't avoid repeating the query. So it seems that I'll have to use subreports or do like you suggested and use table-elements in summary (in both cases I'll be forced to do multiple database queries to achieve the needed grouping).